How do I show that the Lie Derivative of a scalar field is the directional derivative?
We define Lie derivatives of vector fields and differential forms along a vector field as follows:
$(\mathcal L_XY)_m=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{dX_{-t}(Y_{X_t}(m))-Y_m}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(dX_{-t}(Y_{X_t(m)}))$ and $L_X(\omega)_m=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{X_t^*(\omega_{X_t(m)})-\omega_m}{t}=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(X_t^*(\omega_{X_t(m)})$.
Now using these two definitions,how do I show that $\mathcal L_X f=X(f)$ for $f\in C^\infty(M)$?
Maybe It might be easy but for some  reason I cannot see the obvious thing.A $C^\infty$ function can be viewed as a $0$-tensor field/scalar field,but then what is the meaning of $dX_{-t}(f_{Y_{X_t}(m)})$ or $X_t^*(f_{X_t(m)})$,I am a little confused about this.
I need some way to make sense of these things.Please provide a little help.

You’re getting confused because you’re forgetting that pullback of  $(r,s)$ tensor fields has different formulae for different $(r,s)$. The pullback of a function $f$ by a (diffeomorphism in our case) $\phi$ is just $\phi^*f=f\circ \phi$. Now do you see how to modify your work and proceed?

@peek-a-boo Yes,you are correct,now I got it.
